# html small tag is not working inside h1 tag

Tags: html

I am trying to make text small using `<small>` tag inside `<h1>` tag. 
but it seems like it has no effect. everthing seems to be OK. I have attached sample code below for further reference. The specific line I am having problem is this line of code `<h1>#a <small>by limit.broom.flip</small></h1>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chatter|app</title>
    <<style media="screen">
      * {
        background-color: grey;
      }
      h1 {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Channel area  -->
    <h1>chatter|app</h1>
    <h2>#a</h2>
    <h2>#ak</h2>
    <h2>#akr</h2>
    <h2>#akra</h2>
    <h2>#akram</h2>

    <button type="button">New</button>
    <button type="button">Trending</button>
    <button type="button">Favorites</button>

      <hr>
      <!-- chat history area -->
      <h1>#a <small>by limit.broom.flip</small></h1>
      <!-- chat history along with location and ttl -->
      <h4>limit.broom.flip Wed,June 20th, 13:37 <em>15 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Where is London?</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>scout.gifts.bride Wed,June 20th, 13:39 <em>4 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Where is Stratford bus stand?</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>dress.sharp.brave Wed,June 20th, 14:02 <em>12 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>The big apple!</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>derailed.duties.headboard Wed,June 20th, 14:02 <em>7 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Who wants to lost in crowd</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>derailed.duties.headboard Wed,June 20th, 14:07 <em>14 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Stay ahead of traffic</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note you have an extra `<` in `<<style media="screen">`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a simple typo:

```
<<style media="screen">
```

Fix it, and everything will work perfectly

Comment: Did it. Still same. No luck

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
small{
      font-size: medium;
      text-transform: lowercase;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Typo into the your code at `<<style>` element remove extra < your code will work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chatter|app</title>
    <style media="screen">
      * {
        background-color: grey;
      }
      h1 {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Channel area  -->
    <h1>chatter|app</h1>
    <h2>#a</h2>
    <h2>#ak</h2>
    <h2>#akr</h2>
    <h2>#akra</h2>
    <h2>#akram</h2>

    <button type="button">New</button>
    <button type="button">Trending</button>
    <button type="button">Favorites</button>

      <hr>
      <!-- chat history area -->
      <h1>#a <small>by limit.broom.flip</small></h1>
      <!-- chat history along with location and ttl -->
      <h4>limit.broom.flip Wed,June 20th, 13:37 <em>15 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Where is London?</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>scout.gifts.bride Wed,June 20th, 13:39 <em>4 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Where is Stratford bus stand?</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>dress.sharp.brave Wed,June 20th, 14:02 <em>12 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>The big apple!</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>derailed.duties.headboard Wed,June 20th, 14:02 <em>7 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Who wants to lost in crowd</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

      <h4>derailed.duties.headboard Wed,June 20th, 14:07 <em>14 min. left</em></h4>
      <p>Stay ahead of traffic</p>
      <button type="button">+5 min.</button>

  </body>
</html>
```